# What is the diffrence between Tika app, Tika Server and Java Wrapper. Which one is used and when?

Tags: apache-tika, tika-server

I want to use Apache Tika for enterprise-level huge and lots of documents. Which one I use, Tika Server or Tika App or Java calls? Can you suggest me a system architecture? (i.e. Load balanced 3-4 Tika physically different Server)

Comment: How much of the processing will be Tika? And how much of a problem will it be when your JVM crashes or hangs?

Comment: Approximately, daily 5000 documents, each has 500 MB in size.

Comment: 500mb documents are rather large, how much info are you expecting out of them?

Comment: It depends on the file. In general 50-MB of text will be extracted.

Answer (score 0):

Making PUT calls to a REST endpoint for sending thousands of 0.5 GB documents over HTTP, one at a time, is not an appropriate scenario for the Tika Server. It will not be memory efficient and the server [will likely crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53875549/apache-tika-keeps-dying) with some kind of memory leak or bugs.

Although as of v1.19 there is now a `-spawnChild` option to [periodically restart](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/TikaServer#TikaServer-MakingTikaServerRobusttoOOMs,InfiniteLoopsandMemoryLeaks) the process after it has processed `-maxFiles`. From v2.x, this is [now the default](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-3247).

For your needs, you should simply use the `tika-app` in [batch mode](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/tika/TikaBatchUsage), which:

- Runs locally, using an input and output directory that you specify
- Sets up parent/child processes to robustly handle hangs/OOMEs
- Runs multiple parser threads in parallel
- Can restart child every x minutes or after y files to avoid memory leaks
- Logs failures

```
java -jar tika-app.jar -i <input_directory> -o <output_dir>
```